# pd.to_datetime ok but still not as date in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have troubles with my graph using matplotlib and plotly.
I did transform my object date col into a  datetime64[ns] col but I still have the same answer over and over :

"view limit minimum -36834.32000000001 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime unit"

my code to transform object date > datetime :`df_result["date_str"] = pd.to_datetime(df_result['date_str'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')`
then I reduce my dataFrame in the few col I need : `df_graph = df_result[["date_str","frequentation_reel"]]`

when I check, my column 'date_str' is in 'dtype: datetime64[ns]', so it should be ok for a seaborn graph

Here is my code for the plot :`ax1 = sns.barplot(x='date_str', y='frequentation_reel', data = df_graph, palette='summer')`

Here is a sample : `date_str  2017-09-30  frequentation_reel  0.926966`

I tried a lots of things from stackoverflow but nothing works for me so far. I can't figure out what is going wrong. Does anyone can help ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: @BigBen here is a sample : 
`date_str    frequentation_reel<br/>
2017-09-30    0.926966`

Comment: update your question with sample data,  not in a comment